# PureScript - Using Fat Arrow instead of Thin Arrow

Tags: purescript

Consider the following PureScript code, a slightly modified version of an example from the handbook:

```
module ArrayRecursion where

import Prelude (discard, Unit)
import Data.Array (null, tail)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

length :: forall a. Array a => Int
length arr = 
  if null arr then
    0
  else
    1 + ( length $ fromMaybe [] $ tail arr)
```

Compiling this code produces the following error

```
Unknown type class Array
```

So the code won't compile.

The questions:

1. From where is the type class Array imported? It does not seem to be imported from *Prelude* or *Data.Array*.
2. How does one go about finding where to import PureScript type classes? In this case, searching Pursuit for "Array" yields hundreds of results, creating a needle-in-haystack problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array` is not a *type class*, but a *type*.

You accidentally put a fat arrow after `Array a` instead of a thin arrow, making it look like you were declaring a value of type `Int` with a constraint `Array a` rather than a function that takes an `Array a` as a parameter and returns an `Int`. This is how it should look:

```
length :: forall a. Array a -> Int
```

Normally you don't import the `Array` type. It's in the module called `Prim`, which is always implicitly imported.

As for finding out - yes, search on Pursuit. If you carefully look at [the search results](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=Array), you will notice that only one of them (the first one) is actually a type. All the other ones are either functions or ADT cases.

Another way to search for things (especially things in the standard libraries) is your IDE integration. These days I almost never actually have to manually add an import at the top of my files. I just start typing the name of whatever it is I need, and the IDE support offers me some options, waits for me to choose, and automatically adds an import. 10/10 recommend.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I come from JavaScript so thin arrows are still a bit of a mystery. Another slum dunk fren